# Local variable 'char' value is not used - How can I fix this?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm iterating through a list called projects where each project is a string. Then I'm iterating through each project so I can replace every space with an underscore. I know Pycharm is warning because I'm just assigning it and not actually using it. But I'm not trying to use it in the first place. I want to replace it with an underscore only if it's a space, and I don't want to do anything otherwise. How can I fix this?

```
 for project in projects:
        for char in project:
            if char == ' ':
                char = '_' #Local variable 'char' value is not used more... (⌘F1)
```

Comment: from the snippet it looks like you are replacing `space` with `_` in your file names ? and if so doing this way it wont be updating your file names.

Comment: note that in python strings are not mutable so you cannot update a character anyways. You have to create a new string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `project.replace(" ", "_")` to replace the spaces with underscores

But instead of iterating with for loops you could simply use list comprehension to do it all in one line:

```
projects = [project.replace(" ", "_") for project in projects]
```

Comment: project.replace(" ", "_") won't work as project is a list.

Comment: `projects` is a list. `project` (an element of projects) is a string...

Comment: Second syntax will work. But it will give you new strings and not update previous strings.

Answer (score 0):

project = project.replace(" ", "_")

will do the job !

Answer (score 0):

You are not replacing anything, you are creating a new variable called `char` assigned to `'_'`, and then doing nothing with that variable.